# plotly write_image() runs forever and doesn't produce any static image

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, kaleido

## Plotly `fig.write_image()` takes forever

## and doesn't produce any image

I'm using

```
python 3.10.11 
Plotly 5.14.1 
kaleido 0.2.1

Win 11 22H2 
VSCode 1.78.2
```

when I try to execute a cell with `fig.write_image('filename.png', format = 'png')` the cell just runs forever without producing any `.png` files.

Task manager shows 3 kaleido.exe running processes.

Kaleido is installed to the same directroy as plotly (and other packages)

On the contrary, `write_html()` works perfectly with the very same graph and saves a `.html` graph in a second.

**Minimally reproducible example:**

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(x=[0,1,2], y=[0,1,2])
fig.write_image("plot.png", format = 'png', width = 500, height = 500, scale = 1, engine = 'kaleido')
```

Similar questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69016568/unable-to-export-plotly-images-to-png-with-kaleido), [2](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3744), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73401325/plotly-write-image-freezes-with-kaleido-0-2-1)

**Kinda working solution:** downgrading kaleido to `version 0.1.0.post1` kinda solved the issue,

but is there a way to make kaleido 0.2.1 working?

Comment: I am also unable to output with the latest version, so I am using the version down with the [information](https://community.plotly.com/t/static-image-export-hangs-using-kaleido/61519/3) from this post. I have not come across any new information on this yet.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said the right version of kaleido did the trick for me:

```
 conda install -c conda-forge python-kaleido=0.1.0
```

worked for conda

in combination with plotly 5.18.0

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `fig.write_image("image.png")` and `fig.show("png")` were working correctly and then suddenly didn't. Neither reinstalling/downgrading Kaleido nor updating Plotly worked for me.

Restarting the kernel did the trick!